# cannot access file: Input/output error d????????? ? ??

Tags: bash

I'm having the following problem:
I can't remove a specific file

```
$ ls -l
ls: cannot access fisier: Input/output error
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? fisier
$ rm -rf fisier 
rm: cannot remove ‘fisier’: Permission denied
$ sudo rm -rf fisier 
[sudo] password for myusername: 
rm: cannot remove ‘fisier’: Is a directory
```

Comment: Not Operating System, but File System.

Comment: Sorry the file system is sshfs

Comment: It seems that the filesystem can't be accessed anymore. If it is a remote file system (sshfs is a filesystem over a ssh connection) then the remote system seems to be unavailable.